# How to display a dialog box when you click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I would like to display a dialog box when I click the "Forward" button. This dialog must give me the possibility to continue or stay on the same page. How do you do that?

Below is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
        <title>Test</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      modal: true, 
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
          $('#valid');
          //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "No": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });

</script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Box">
    </div>
    <p>Welcome...!</p>
    <input type="file"/>
    <input type="submit" id="valider" name="valid" value="Forward"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any form that you are submiiting ? i dont see any form in html

Comment: How do I click a button when I have a dialog message ?

Comment: Have a look at window.location.assign https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Example_1_Navigate_to_a_new_page

Comment: `<input type="submit" id="valider" name="valid" value="Forward" />` should be inside a `<form>` tag if you want to submit it

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you..

```
if (confirm("your message")) {

    // your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a `<form>` element. Then add assign an id, a target file and an [`onsubmit`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) function. We'll write `return firstModal()`.

Let's create `firstModal()`: using the [`.dialog`](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) from jQuery UI we create a modal with two options: one <kbd>Close</kbd> and the other <kbd>Send</kbd>. Then we link the first to `$(this).dialog("close")` to close the dialog and the other to `document.getElementById("myForm").submit()` which allows to submit the HTML form to the target file set in `action`.

Here's the full working code:

You can create two modal boxes: one for the initial input then another for the confirmation:

```js
let confirmFormDialog = function(form) {

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Send: function() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
      },
      Close: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  
  return false;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="dialog" title="Box"></div>
<p>Welcome...!</p>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return confirmFormDialog()" action="targetFile.php">
  <input type="file" />
  <input type="submit" id="valider" name="valid" value="Forward" />
</form>
```

Using this technique we need to make sure that [`confirmFormDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) returns `false`. This way the HTML form doesn't submit when the input button is clicked. By removing this default behavior we decide when to submit the form with `.submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need To add click event listener to show dialog on click of `Forward` Button

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="dialog" title="Box"></div>
<p>Welcome...!</p>
<input type="file" />
<input type="submit" id="valider" name="valid" value="Forward" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("valider").addEventListener("click",function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Yes: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        No: function() {
          console.log('clicked no');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the background color of the dialog box because the default color is not displayed well and we do not see the dialog box

Comment: add 
<style>
.ui-dialog,.ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all, .foo, .ui-draggable, .ui-resizable {background:yellow !important}​
</style>
in `head` tag it will turn dialog box color to yellow.