# How to Update Status of Message From unread to read using Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have to update the status of a message once the user reads or click on the anchor tag so that the particular message is taken off the list.

i am expecting to use ajax to update the status.
This is what i have done so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('counterBackground').html = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Message/GetMessages",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#counter').html(data.length);
                   
            let messages = `
                        <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <div>
                                <img>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <h5><span><small>

                                                    <time><span></span></time>

                                                </small></span></h5>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>`
                ;


            for (let m of data) {
                messages += `<ul><li>
                        <a href="">
                            <div class="message-avatar">
                                <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="message-body">
                                <div class="message-body-heading">
                                    <h5>${m.subject}<span> <small class="fa-pull-right">
                                                    <time class="timeago" datetime=""><span>${m.createdDate}</span></time>
                                                </small></span></h5>
                                    
                                   
                                </div>
                                <p>${m.body}</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>`
            
            // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
            document.getElementById("messageList").innerHTML = messages;
             
            }
            
      
            
            console.log(data);
            },
        
        error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
    });


})
$(function IsRead() {
    $.ajax({
        Type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Message/UpdateMsgStatus",
        traditional: true,
        data: { msgId: Id },
        success: function (result) {
            result.IsRead=1
        }
    });
})
```

in my controller, the method is this

```
       public JsonResult  UpdateMsgStatus(string Id)
       {

           var msg= ctx.Messages.Where(m => m.MessageId == Id).FirstOrDefault();
           if (msg != null)
           {
               msg.MessageId=Id;
               msg.IsRead = 1;
               ctx.SaveChanges();
           }
           return Json(msg);
       }
```

and this is my list of messages
[image]
any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to update the status of a message once the user reads or click
> on the anchor tag

ajax would only update the message in your current page,if you want to update the messages in other tabs,pages once you've read the message like stackoverflow's inbox,you have to try with other tech,such as [signalr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

for the element created after `$(document).ready()`,you have to bind the event to document instead of the element

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.message', function (e) {
        $(this).hide()
    })
</script>
```

also,since you are working with asp.net core,you could create a partial view instead of writting plenty html  in your jquery codes

full minimal example:

```
    <span id="counter">
</span>
<div class="messagebox">
    
</div>




<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",        
        url: "/Home/MessagePartial",        
        success: function (data) { 
            $('.messagebox').html(data)
            $('#counter').html($('.message').length)
        }
    })
</script>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.message', function (e) {
        $(this).hide()
        $('#counter').html($('.message:not([style*="display: none"])').length)
    
    })
</script>
```

Partial View controller:

```
    public IActionResult MessagePartial()
    {
        // in your case,you have to query the messages in db
        var messages = new string[] { "Hi", "messages1", "messages2", "messages3"};
        return PartialView(messages);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
    @model string[]
    
    @foreach(var message in Model)
    {
        <div class="message">
            @message
        </div>
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: do you suggest that i can achieve that with viewcomponent or partial view?.  I do not want to use signalR because i want to persist the messages in the database.

Comment: You could  move the codes of your inbox into partialview ,every time you click the message,send an ajax call to your controller that return a new partial view ,update your current partial view with  $('.messagebox').html(data),it would be much more convenient  for you to update the inbox

Comment: You could open two tabs  and click the message in inbox of stackoverflow,you would find the messages in another tab would be  updated automaticlly.If you want to achieve it, you have to try with real -time tech such as signalr,call the js codes to update your another  tab on serverside

Comment: thank you for your help. I followed your suggestions and it help. However, the generated div is going over my navbar.  I am finding it difficult to let it stay where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Hi,@Katakyie Kofi Poku,would you show  the html codes related?

Comment: how do i toggle the button so that the message can only show when i click on the button

Comment: how do i toggle the button so that the message can only show when i click on the button--Do you mean the inbox icon is your button?

Comment: yes, the inbox icon is my button

Comment: does the issue help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838807/how-to-display-a-dialog-box-when-you-click-a-button

Comment: following your suggestions and comments, I have been able to get the messages showing up.  However, after reading the messages or clicking on it, the whole notificationlist hides instead of the exact message.  That means i always have to reload the notificationlist again.
$(document).on('click', '.message', function (e) 
{
    $(this).hide()
    $('#counter').html($('.message:not([style*="display: none"])').length)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Message/UpdateMessage",
        data: {Id:$("#msgId").val()},
    })
});
.